# How can I send a notification to all devices?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

How can I send a notification to all devices registered in my Firebase notification service? I mean, I know how to send it to one device using its token but I don't know how to send it to all devices without explicitly passing the token of each device.

Comment: Check out my answer . You can sent message to  multiple device using request_id array . check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975786/gcm-push-notification-sending-taking-very-long-time-in-php?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Or you can subscribe to topic message and publish message as topic. check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using firebase u can send notification on multiple device check this link it will helpfull  for u

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple