# Shall i use FIREBASE CONSOLE to send push notification to all users everytime?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have successfully implemented FCM with my android application, I am able to send push notification through firebase console. But shall I use firebase console to send these notifications every time or do I need to make my own Application(like some admin application) to do this?

Comment: try this answer to send fcm message using php  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975786/gcm-push-notification-sending-taking-very-long-time-in-php?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: That can be done from server side

Comment: Either using the Notifications console, or sending messages through the API are valid options. It all depends on your . There is no way for us to answer what you should do here.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should use Firebase Cloud Functions for this. Using Cloud Functions you can set a condition and if your condition satisfies, Pust Notification will be sent to all or a particular user automatically.

To know more about Cloud Functions click [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

Answer (score 0):

Things are simple if you are the only one who is going to push notifications then its better to push through firebase console because its already there for you.
Other wise you can make your own application for sending push notifications easily.
Depends totally on your need.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to send notifications. One such is via firebase console. If you want to send notification through other applications then it can be using `Postman`. [Here you can refer this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834020/sending-push-via-postman-using-firebase-messaging) by this you can send notification to particular device and for the topics too.

Hope this may help.