# Firebase notification curl with timeout

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification

I am using firebase notification for communicate with android applications with Laravel / PHP server,

My code for PHP :

```
$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $fcm_id, /* array for fcm ids */
    'data' => $data
);

$headers = array(
   'Authorization: key=/*My Key*/',
   'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This code is working fine but takes too much time when there is large numbers of registration ids, to overcome this problem i have to use background process for curl, so that i use timeout_ms in curl
like :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 10);
```

but when i use this line, notification not sent to android.

my question is why execution of fcm stops when i using this line, or is there any other way to do background process for FCM Notification?

Comment: Firebase providing max 1000 limit of user to send notifications at a time. You have to use some loops like first 1000 users then second 1000 users etc...

Comment: I have already using loops for 1000 fcm_ids, but still time is quite large, i want to execute above curl in background.

Comment: Background means on server side or app side? and where its take much time? to get android side or while sending from web side?

Comment: try background use the shell_exec  like https://medium.com/@jituboss/php-non-blocking-curl-requests-to-firebase-for-push-notifications-8cd613043327

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45978377/1318946

Comment: @PratikButaniAndroidDev i want to run process in server side, when i save anything it should be save in few seconds, but it takes some longer time to save due to notification process.

Comment: @GhanshyamNakiya curl also provide a timeout function for async process, then why its not working in this curl?

Comment: @Arjun for that you can do one thing that, create trigger for particular table and send notification when trigger occurred, so you can save time at the time of insertion and it will send notification after inserting and trigger being called.